# linked image in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

How can I create a linked image with reStructuredText?

I've found

```
.. image:: /path/to/image.jpg
```

for images, and external hyperlinks like

```
'Python <http://www.python.org/>'_
```

for links, but I don't know how to combine them or if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

1. in inline images:

   ```
   .. image:: pageflip-200.png
      :target: pageapplet/index.html
   ```
2. With a reference, like:

   ```
   Click on my |ImageLink|_

   .. |ImageLink| image:: /images/link.png
   .. _ImageLink: http://link.url/
   ```

Comment: Actually, example 1 generates a block-level image while example 2 generates an inline image.

Comment: The inline image doesn't seem to work in GitHub's Markdown renderer. In PyPI (pypi.org) it does work.

Answer (score 3):

The following site has a reference for reStructuredText but also Markdown, MediaWiki, asciidoc & org-mode.

http://hyperpolyglot.org/lightweight-markup

Comment: *...who upvoted this?* By no sane criteria do external links satisfy even the bare modicum of the criteria needed to qualify as an answer. Work with us here, people.

Comment: Should I remove it? I think it's a very useful reference even if it does not answer the question directly since there was already a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:target:` option of the "image" or "figure" directive:

```
.. image:: /path/to/image.jpg
   :target: http://www.python.org/
```

Works also for an inline image:

```
.. |inline-image| image:: /path/to/image.jpg
   :target: http://www.python.org/
   :height: 1em

Paragraph with |inline-image|
```

For details, see the [reStructuredText Directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) and the [reStructuredText Markup Specification](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions).